# inner loop (breakable) alternative with the same performance

Tags: java, scala, performance, loops, break

how it looks in Java:

```java
public void perform() {
    outer: while (someCondition) {
        while(someCollection.nonEmpty() && anotherCondition) {
            if (otherCondition) 
                break outer;
            else doSomething();
        }

       try {
          doSomethingWithException();
       } catch (Exception e) {
          break; // breaks outer loop
       }

       doSomethingAnother();
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest an alternative in Scala?

i already know about util.control.Breaks, but are there any other alternatives?

Comment: I guess it wasn't `nonEmpty`. Anyways, they may be alternatives, but you should be more specific about your code. What do you do with each element of the collection, how is other condition computed?

Comment: A big problem with this question is that the code, as presented, violates some core FP principals, such as referential transparency and the like. The Scala way would start with: "What is actually being accomplished?" But that information isn't offered.

Comment: @jwvh, no no, buddy, let's skip the FP principles and try to concentrate on the main task: exit the nested loop

i'm just need to break inner loop  when some condition is true

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, okay :) could we please skip the moment with collection? 
my main goal is break the loop when some condition is true, and it's not hard to implement in Java/Scala with break, but i'm looking for alternative way

Comment: The first tool in repetition control is recursion. Not always simple or elegant (sometimes but not always) but it offers control features hard to find in other options.

Comment: @jwvh thanks! but could you please show some example? if i got right i'm need to pass some boolean flag (break or not) at each recursive call ?

Comment: @jwvh something like this:

```scala
@tailrec
def recLoop(cond: Boolean): Unit  = {
   if (cond) {
      doSomething()
      ...
      
   }
   recLoop(refToCond)
}
```

Comment: @Code_VM so what do you mean with alternatives? I thought that meant idiomatic Scala, that would be FP as jwvh said, which also means we need to understand what do you want to do. Other alternatives include boolean flags as shown in the answer, recursion as mentioned before or higher order methods with early return semantics like `exists`. Finally, you also mention performance, that is another big topic which makes the question more broad, I would just focus on the alternatives for now and then worry about performance latter, in any case, if it matters for you, then benchmark!

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your code to something like this:

```
  var continueWhileCondition = true
  while (someCondition && continueWhileCondition) {
    while (someOtherCondition) {
      if (someThirdCondition) {
        continueWhileCondition = false
      }
    }
    if (continueWhileCondition) {
      //here do try/catch
    }
  }
```

Just add additional condition that will break while.
But this is not FP solution, and you should really use recursion.

Comment: thanks a lot! but what about performance?

it's can be replaced with

```scala
loopByCond(cond: => Boolean)(funcBody: => Unit): Unit = {
    if (cond) {
        funcBody
        loopByCond(cond)(funcBody)
    }
}
```
and my problem is break outer loop in inner loop, when some another condition is true

Comment: I am not sure what is your question here, and what is code that you posted.
You will break outer loop with changing var continueWhileCondition to false inside inner loop, in next iteration you will exit outer while. If you do not want to continue inner loop you can set  someOtherCondition to false too. In that way you will exit both loops when someThirdCondition is true. 
Performance will not be changed as this boolean variable can be checked very fast.